# Colorize row based on a field value on kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Is there any way to colorize or, in general, apply styles to results table on Kibana 4? I'm talking about the *discover* result table.

Basically, our logs have a *level* field and we want to add colors on the result table based on its value, so they can be easily recognized. E.g: Error messages should be red, warning messages yellow.

I know elastic search has some [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) capabilities but know do not how to use them with kibana

Comment: This looks a lot like this pending issue: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1304

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm looking for color coded rows based on string values, which is exactly this issue:  https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/6348

Answer (score 5):

Update:
You can now color Strings easily:

1. log into kibana
2. go to Management (settings)
3. click "index patterns" and choose your pattern
4. click on Severity (or whatever name your logs have there), then click on edit (you can also do it for a service or other columns)
5. in "Format" choose 'Color', Then in 'Pattern' write INFO or a pattern you would like and choose the corresponding color

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [custom formatters](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-custom-field-formatters) is the way to go. I.e: writing a new component using JavaScript and Html

This example creates a formatter to highlight text. It's not exactly what is being asked, but it should work as base.